# move_Image_upload is showing error.

Tags: php

I'm using the below code to upload member's profile picture. As I'm new to php, I not able to capture where is the problem.
When i try to uplaod a file error shows:

```
"move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move 'C:\Windows\Temp\phpF574.tmp' to '/profilepic/loader.gif'"
```

My code is below:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['pic'])){
$dir="/profilepic/";
$tmp_nm=$_FILES['profilepic']['tmp_name']; 

 $extension = pathinfo($_FILES['profilepic']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
 if (($extension !=="jpg") && 
 ($extension !=="jpeg") && 
 ($extension !=="png") && 
 ($extension !=="gif")) 
        {

            exit('<div class="error" align="center">Unknown Image uploaded.</div> ');
        }

$size=filesize($_FILES['profilepic']['tmp_name']);
if ($size > 200*1024)
{
    $change='<div class="error">Maximum 200 KB Image Size allowed!</div> ';
}

$filename=$_FILES['profilepic']['name'];    
@move_uploaded_file($tmp_nm, $dir.$filename);
$arr=array("profilepic='$filename'");
$class_database->update($arr, profile_table, "profileid='".$_SESSION['id']."'");
echo ('<div align="center" class="success">Uploaded your profile picture.</div>'.$php_errormsg);
}
?>
```

Also may anyone help me ?

Comment: If your webserver is a unix based system, than check, if the permissions of `/profilepic/` are set to `777`.

Comment: No it's not UNIX, the hint is in the file path of the first quote.

Comment: @Jon: That just means it could be a WAMP setup.

Comment: @Herbert Yea, I should probably have @'d leo with that comment really. My bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Unable to move 'C:\Windows\Temp\phpF574.tmp' to '/profilepic/loader.gif'"` usually means that you either don't have permission to write to `/profilepic` or that directory doesn’t exist.

1. Make sure `/profilepic` directory actually exists.
2. Check `$_FILES['profilepic']['error']` for anything other than 0

Comment: Ya, I havenot created the directory. Thanks for solution

Comment: @Indian Girl: I had this exact same problem yesterday. Some file functions create the directory for you. Apparently `move_uploaded_file` does not.

Comment: yaa, you are right. Herbert may you give me some hint about the above code related to security thread?

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't understand what you're asking me.